# mpiexec : multiple program multiple data failed with parameters

Tags: mpi

According to [this page](http://physics.princeton.edu/it/cluster/docs/mpich2/www1/mpiexec.html). If we run

```
mpiexec -n 4 ocean : -n 8 air
```

it will run the program ocean on 4 processes and air on 8 processes

But I have fortran program used mpi and mkl. I compiled it using intel fortran `mpiifort` and link to mkl. Also the program accept 7 argements. Individual run like

```
./a.out 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

has no problem. It print 3 lines of message on screen and generate a file with name according to input command line args.

Then I tried

```
mpiexec.hydra -n 1 ./a.out 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 : -n 1 ./a.out 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

it can only run `./a.out 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` part. `./a.out 0 0 0 0 0 0 1` is not running.

Here is snapshot of running

[image]

What are possible cause of failure running?

Comment: You must give us many more details. Your code, your MPI library version, your compiler, the exact input and output.

Comment: Hi, @VladimirF. Thank you for your reply. My code is complex. But it is in fortran. I use intel fortran compiler and ./a.out is compiled with `mpiifort` though I used it as single process in this case. The output is a data file and some print messages. There is no file input, except the command line parameter

Comment: so you are using Intel MPI ? first try something simpler such as `mpiexec -n 1 echo foo : -n 1 echo bar`, does it work as expected ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet yeah, it works.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet You enlightened me. I write a simple bash script that accept 3 args. and `mpiexec -n 1 bash test.bash 1 2 3 : -n 1 bash test.bash 5 6 7 : -n 1 bash test.bash 7 8 9` works. So is it due to my `./a.out` is compiled with mpi?

Comment: so that seems to point to your code instead of the MPI library. you can try with a simple MPI hello world that prints the parameters passed on the command line to confirm that.

Comment: Hi, @GillesGouaillardet. I done a little test. I write a little mpi fortran program which accept 2 integer args, and write a file with name according to args. Then I run `mpiexec.hydra -n 1 ./a.out 1 2 : -n 1 ./a.out 3 4 : -n 1 ./a.out 5 6`. It works. This makes things oddly enough. What other possible factor made my program fail?

Comment: Are you sure your initial Fortran program reads its arguments on the command line? Doesn't it rather read it from the standard input like many Fortran codes do (like `echo 1 2 3  | ./a.out`)?

Comment: @Gilles yeah, I am sure. I use `get_command_argument` in my program. And the fact is that simply running `./a.out 1 2 3` etc is working without any problem.

Comment: what did you mean by `./a.out 0 0 1` is ignored ? only one MPI task is started ? 2 MPI tasks are started as `./a.out 0 0 0` ? also, do you `get_command_argument` before or after `MPI_Init()` in both your app and the test program ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I means only `./a.out 0 0 0` run, `./a.out 0 0 1` is not running. There is only message and file for parameter "0 0 0" generated

Comment: how many MPI tasks for `./a.out 0 0 0` ? 1 or 2 ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Here is my snapshot of running https://pasteboard.co/H4SmBNW.png . My actual parameter number is 7

Comment: Please [edit] your queations and add all details in a structured way. Do NOT use comments for important information. Make a smalk test code, show it **completely** and show the **complete** output. Rewrite the question, do not 7se comments. You have already more than 600 reputationx you should have some experience from using Stack Overflow.

Comment: @VladimirF Sorry, because at first, I did realize the problem is not due command line argument. I will edit it.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? your command should spawn 2 MPI tasks that are part of the same `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. If you want to run two independent programs, at the same time, then this is not very natural from a MPI point of view, but you can be achieved if your code is correctly written.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I had a  such worry before but don't know how to solve it. But wait a minute, I said I tested a simple mpi program before, and it works. So maybe this is not the real issue.

Comment: From the `mpiexec` point of view, everything seems fine. i still do not understand what you meant by `./a.out 0 0 0 0 0 0 1` is not running, nor what you are trying to achieve/solve. Feel free to ask a new question if you can clearly describe that.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Ok, I actually want to run a set of different parameters. And each parameter generate a data file. But I want to parallel the running. I can write python script using `multiprocessing` package to parallel external program running. But it is limited on one node. I work on a cluster, I want to parallelize it across several nodes, because I have hundreds of parameters to do. As far as I know, mpi is the simplest way to parallelize across node on my cluster, because it automatically discover nodes and  handles internode connections.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I actually also tried to use mpi4py in python, since it has more friendly map operation, so I can map os.system over a command list. But it works for non-mpi program, crashes for mpi program

Comment: What if you do **not** call `MPI_Init()` in your app then ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I am afraid simply comment out `MPI_Init()` is not working. I got `Attempting to use an MPI routine before initializing MPI`. It seems that I need to delete all mpi statement, that will be a lot of work

Comment: then an other option is to revamp your app, and use `MPI_Comm_spawn()` to start each "individual" run. If you are running via a resource manager, Job Array could be an easier alternative. Meanwhile, without a clear description of what you are trying to achieve, and ideally a [MCVE], it will be hard for me to help.